# google calendar feed won't import

Tags: google-calendar-api, icalendar

I've been at this for hours now and I can't seem to get this feed to import to google calendar:
http://newtest.wpengine.com/programs/?ical=1

It imports fine when I download it then import it as a file. I even tried making it bare bones with just a few lines. It gets 100% in this validator: http://icalvalid.cloudapp.net/. Can anyone spot what i'm missing. here is the file

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//Blue Mandala Retreat Site
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
METHOD:PUBLISH
X-WR-CALNAME:Deryk Wenaus Blog
X-WR-TIMEZONE: 
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:http://ayahuas.ca/program/sample-program/
DTSTAMP:20130110T001222Z
CONTACT:
DESCRIPTION: a nice program. a nice program.
DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:20130124
DTEND;VALUE=DATE:20130127
LOCATION:
SUMMARY:sample program
URL:http://ayahuas.ca/program/sample-program/
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

the error i keep getting from google calendar is `The address that you provided did not contain a calendar in a valid iCal or GData format.`

I'm using `header( 'Content-type: text/calendar; charset=UTF-8' );` as the header, and I've also tried `header( 'Content-Disposition: inline; filename="calendar.ics"' );` with no luck.

Comment: which http header do you set for serving the file? for did you try instance setting  'Content-Type: text/calendar;'

Comment: i updated the question with the header info.

Answer (score 1):

Google Calendar uses GoogleBot to request information of the calendar on your site. Maybe your server is preventing GoogleBot for entering in the ICal URL. Check your robots.txt

Answer (score 0):

it is most likely the fact that you have specified a URL property value which does not point to your ics file itself.

the same icalendar file without the URL property should work (I tried to upload your icalendar file in google calendar via the file and not the url and it worked but it kept on trying to load a calendar, when removing the URL property this disappeared).

Comment: so if I make my url something like this it should work? `http://newtest.wpengine.com/programs/calendar.ics` is that what you mean by url property?

Comment: more inside the ics file: `URL:http://newtest.wpengine.com/programs/calendar.ics`